# Не удается удалить элемент с массива в localstorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Записываю значения я таким способом:

```
    //isEmpty - моя ф-ция, которая проверяет пустой ли объект
    //item - это обычный стринг
    if (isEmpty(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')))) {
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify([item]));
    } else {
        var localTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
        localTodos.push(item);
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(localTodos));
    }
```

Столкнулась с тем, что нужно добавить возможность удалить какую-то запись при нажатии на кнопку. Т.е. если на входе получаю массив вида

```
todos: ['123', '12', '1']
```

и мне нужно удалить элемент с индексом 1, то должен получиться

```
todos: ['123', '1']
```

Индекс я записсываю в `value` кнопки и при нажатии его вытягиваю и пытаюсь удалить запись таким способом:

```
    //todoId - индекс элемента
    var todos    = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    var newTodos = todos.splice(todoId, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos));
```

Но на выходе получается какая-то белеберда и удаляются все записи кроме выбранной. Не подскажете как можно сделать по-другому?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`splice` меняет сам массив, а возвращает удалённый элемент

```
var todos    = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
todos.splice(todoId, 1);
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
```

Comment: спасибо, не заметила. на такой глупости застряла)

Comment: js коварный и отвратительный